# Test for correctness of datatypes of function arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, assert, chai

I am using assert-type module to test for correctness of datatypes of function arguments.

Sample code of what I did;

```
var cs = require("coffee-script/register");//this line needed to require("assert-type"). Some bug.
var ty = require("assert-type"); //https://github.com/mlin/node-assert-type
var T = ty.Assert;

function test_func(file_name, start_time, end_time) {
    T(ty.str, ty.obj.not.null, ty.obj.not.null)(file_name, start_time, end_time);
    //action code
}
```

What is the corresponding code if I were to use chaijs module? http://chaijs.com/

I went through the documentation but failed to find the corresponding code. Should I stick to using assert-type module?

Answer (score 0):

Use chaijs type-detect.
https://github.com/chaijs/type-detect

```
var type = require('type-detect');
assert(type(file_name) === "string");
assert(type(start_time) !== "null");
assert(type(end_time) !== "null");
```